# Docker build failing when ARG instruction is given before FROM in dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

docker build --build-arg DOCKER_REGISTRY=in-docker-reg.citrite.net --build-arg CTX_REST_PROXY_VERSION="3.1.0" -f build/docker/dev/rest_proxy_dockerfile -t mr-kafka-rest--service .

Sending build context to Docker daemon 988.3 MB

Step 1 : ARG DOCKER_REGISTRY

Please provide a source image with `from` prior to commit

Makefile:10: recipe for target 'docker_build' failed

make: *** [docker_build] Error 1

Dockerfile starts with ARG instruction:

```
ARG DOCKER_REGISTRY
FROM $(DOCKER_REGISTRY):5000/mr-kafka-rest/nsoslx-1.2-18-x64-docker-cp-kafka-rest-base:latest
```

I believe we can use ARG before FROM but i seem to be missing something, please help.
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact

Comment: which version of docker? You might be using a old one

Comment: Docker version 1.12.6, build 78d1802

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should refer to the Docker Release notes https://docs.docker.com/release-notes/docker-ce/

The feature you are using was introduce in `17.05.0-ce (2017-05-04)`

> **Builder**
>
> Add multi-stage build support #31257 #32063
>
> Allow using build-time args (ARG) in FROM [#31352](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/31352)

You need to upgrade

Comment: thanks tarun , i will upgrade and update the findings.